# Same value but different result? About removeSparseTerms (R)

Tags: r

First af all, here is the example data to reproduce the problem that I have and I will try to explain bellow:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RCdYlVF8otUll6V2x0cDJORGc/view?usp=sharing

The matter is that I get different results from removeSparseTerms despite of introducing it the same value. It seems defying the human logic, or at least the mine one. I have this function:

```
generateTDM <- function (Room_name, dest.train, RST){
          s.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s", dest.train, Room_name)
          s.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, pattern = "txt", encoding = "UTF-8"))                  #Crea unos corpora de los archivos txt ya limpios.
          s.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor, control = list(bounds = list(local = c(2, Inf)), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))                     #Crea una matriz de terminos a partir de los corpora teniendo en cuenta unigramas, bigramas y trigramas.
          s.tdm <- removeSparseTerms(s.tdm, RST)                                                           #Mantiene aquellos términos que aparezcan en el (1-RST)% de los archivos, el resto los elimina.
      }
```

Well, when I invoke this function this way:

```
tdm.train <- lapply(Room_name, generateTDM, dest.train, RST[p])
```

I obtain different outputs in function of where is the variable RST located inside a vector depending on the other elements. That is to say, despite being the same value, I get distinct results.

For example:

**Case 1:**

```
RST <-seq (0.45, 0.6, 0.05)
p<-4
```

I will have RST = (0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6), then RST[p] is 0.6.

The result in this case:

```
    > tdm.train 
        [[1]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 84, documents: 51)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 2451/1833
    Sparsity           : 43%
    Maximal term length: 10
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    [[2]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 82, documents: 52)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 2409/1855
    Sparsity           : 44%
    Maximal term length: 11
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    [[3]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 68, documents: 51)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 1926/1542
    Sparsity           : 44%
    Maximal term length: 13
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    [[4]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 36, documents: 48)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 985/743
    Sparsity           : 43%
    Maximal term length: 10
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    [[5]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 48, documents: 50)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 1295/1105
    Sparsity           : 46%
    Maximal term length: 10
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    [[6]]
    <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 27, documents: 50)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 756/594
    Sparsity           : 44%
    Maximal term length: 8
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

**Case 2:**

```
    RST <-seq (0.45, 0.8, 0.05)
    p<-4
```

I will have now that RST = (0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8), ergo RST[p] is the same this time (0.6).

Then, why I have a different result? I can't understand it.

```
> tdm.train
[[1]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 84, documents: 51)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2451/1833
Sparsity           : 43%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

[[2]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 82, documents: 52)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2409/1855
Sparsity           : 44%
Maximal term length: 11
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

[[3]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 68, documents: 51)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1926/1542
Sparsity           : 44%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

[[4]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 36, documents: 48)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 985/743
Sparsity           : 43%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

[[5]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 57, documents: 50)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1475/1375
Sparsity           : 48%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

[[6]]
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 34, documents: 50)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 896/804
Sparsity           : 47%
Maximal term length: 8
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I don't know... it's very strange, right?. If the value of RST is the same, why the result of removeSparseTerms in the last two dirs are different in each case. Please, help me, don't knowing the reason is killing me.

Thank you so much and have a nice day.

---

Reproducible example based on the OP's update:

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
download.file("https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B4RCdYlVF8otUll6V2x0cDJORGc&export=download", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), mode = "wb")
unzip(tf, exdir = tempdir())
TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 3))
generateTDM <- function (Room_name, dest.train, rst){
  s.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s", dest.train, Room_name)
  s.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, pattern = "txt", encoding = "UTF-8"))                  #Crea unos corpora de los archivos txt ya limpios.
  s.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor, control = list(bounds = list(local = c(2, Inf)), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))                     #Crea una matriz de terminos a partir de los corpora teniendo en cuenta unigramas, bigramas y trigramas.
  t <- table(s.tdm$i) > (s.tdm$ncol * (1 - rst)) # from tm::removeSparseTerms()
  termIndex <- as.numeric(names(t[t]))
  return(s.tdm[termIndex, ])
}
dest.train <- file.path(tempdir(), "stackoverflow", "TrainDocs")
Room_name <- "Venus"
p <- 4
RST1 <- seq(0.45, 0.6, 0.05)
RST2 <- seq(0.45, 0.8, 0.05)
RST2[p]
# [1] 0.6
RST1[p]
# [1] 0.6
identical(RST2[p], RST1[p])
# [1] FALSE # ?!?

lapply(Room_name, generateTDM, dest.train, RST1[p])
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 48, documents: 50)>>

lapply(Room_name, generateTDM, dest.train, RST2[p])
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 57, documents: 50)>> # ?!?
```

Comment: Imho it would habe been better to highlight the differences and provide example data for reproduction instead of stressing "I don't know... I can't understand it" multiple times. :-)

Comment: Yeah, true. I'll prepare a zip with the important documents and parts of the script to attach here as soon as posible. Sorry for that.

Comment: Done. Example data attached and level of stress in the sentences decreased... a bit. :)

Comment: Interesting. `identical(RST2[p], RST1[p])` is `FALSE`, which I don't understand, and it seems thus `table(m$i) > m$ncol * (1 - sparse)` inside `removeSparseTerms` gives slightly different results.

Comment: Thanks lukeA for your time and effort. The reproducible example, which you have done, is awesome and much more clear. Thanks for that, I already know how to share code properly next time.

About the question, I used `all.equal` and `str` to compare both values (I didn't know the instruction `identical`), so I supposed that they were the same, because is like it should be. Really, really strange. :S

Comment: Jep. Let's wait until readers with deeper R-knowledge shed some light on the prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the popular question "[7.31 Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)":

> The only numbers that can be represented exactly in R’s numeric type
>   are integers and fractions whose denominator is a power of 2. All
>   other numbers are internally rounded to (typically) 53 binary digits
>   accuracy. As a result, two floating point numbers will not reliably be
>   equal unless they have been computed by the same algorithm, and not
>   always even then

Given

```
(x <- seq(0.45, 0.6, 0.05))
# [1] 0.45 0.50 0.55 0.60
(y <- seq(0.45, 0.8, 0.05))
# [1] 0.45 0.50 0.55 0.60 0.65 0.70 0.75 0.80
```

then

```
x==y
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[4]==y[4]
# [1] FALSE
x[4]-y[4]
# [1] -1.110223e-16
x[3]-y[3]
# [1] 0
```

Since

```
MASS::as.fractions(x)
# [1]  9/20   1/2 11/20   3/5
```

I guess the two `.5` are reliably equal here. Thus, your function may yield different results.

Comment: Thank you very much lukeA. Following your response I managed to solve the problem by creating the RST vector with integer values: `RST <-seq (45, 60, 5)`, and at time to invoke the function, I enter the RST value divided between 100:  `tdm.train <- lapply(Room_name, TDM_roomRST, dest.train, (RST[p]/100))`. Thus the result I get is already exactly the same in each case. Seriously, I really apreciate your help and implication here mate. I wish you the best. Greetings and thank you.